# Cannot initialize array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a global array in a js file: `var buttonsClicked;` and I instantiate it inside `$(document).ready(function ()`. Later I call push method of array buttonsClicked but I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null`

```
var buttonsClicked;

$(document).ready(function () {

    buttonsClicked = new Array();
}

function f() {
    buttonsClicked.push("some string");
}
```

The f() method is call later when the user trigger some buttons from frontend. I don't know why this array is null even that the new Array() seems to be called. In the browser console the array is also null.

Comment: Post the full code?

Comment: I have just edited the question. I can't post the entire js file, is too much larger.

Comment: `The f() method is call later` That's key to the question - post how you're trying to use it.

Comment: in the html file I have something like:```<button type="button" onclick="f()"/>```

Comment: It looks like you'd override `buttonsClicked` variable with `null` somewhere before clicking the button. If the variable couldn't be found at all, the error message would be slightly different: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property or method 'push' of undefined."

Comment: *buttonsClicked* should not be null. It might be undefined, but the code you’ve posted doesn’t demonstrate the behaviour you claim.

Comment: Pls check were ever you have used `buttonsClicked` and see whether it has been assigned with a null value. If possible post the code where ever you have used `buttonsClicked`

Answer (score 0):

Use a modern browser – at least for development – so you can use `const` and catch the error where you re-define `buttonsClicked`. Change the code as follow:

```
const buttonsClicked = [];

function f() {
  buttonsClicked.push("some string");
}
```

At this point, if in any part of your code you're trying to override `buttonsClicked`, you will get an error, and you will see where you're assigning it. If this doesn't happen, the string "some string" will be added.